# what's Wrong with Menu

Tags: php, magento

I have this code for my top.phtml file

```
<div class="header-nav-container">
    <div class="header-nav">
        <h4 class="no-display"><?php echo $this->__('Category Navigation:') ?></h4>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></a></li>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
                <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Contact Us') ?></a></li>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('aboutus') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('About Us') ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLeftLinks') ?>
</div>
```

but this show only Home,Contact Us and About Us Link

i also have added categories by going **catalog->Manage categories** but i am not able to see this categories in Top Navigation Menu

Comment: why isn't `<?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>` inside a <li> tag, because I presume you want to add thes categories as list items of the menu.

Comment: <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?> will auto add list in LI

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: What do you get when using this code: `<?php echo count($this->getStoreCategories()); ?>`

Comment: same thing it also shows nothing

Comment: Nothing, or you have a **0** echoed between </li> <li> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() gives you the expected store id ?
2. Does Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() gives you the expected category id ?
3. Have you sellable (in stock, with qty, enabled, ...) products in this categories ?
4. Are your indexes up to date ?
5. Have you tried to clean your cache ?

Comment: Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); shows 2...i checked it now

Comment: So is this category id 2 is the category that have the desired categories to be displayed attached ?
What about other questions ?